# Modal form not submitting user input

Tags: ajax

I have a modal form which allows user to add a new row to a table on a PHP webpage, then refreshes the page. But modal form is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment I see that you have error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

it is because missing jQuery, add this line before the `</head>`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

now you can submit the form using Ajax but your script is invalid

```
$.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) {
  var d1 = JSON.parse(data);
  location.href = location.href;  <-- here
```

It will refresh the page no matter if it `success` or `error` and here fixed code

```
var ajax_url = "<?php echo APPURL;?>/ajax.php";

$(document).on('click', '.submitBtn', function(event) {

  var datamapname = $('#inputName').val();
  var description = $('#inputDescription').val();

  var data_obj = {
    call_type: 'new_row_entry_vdm',
    datamapname: datamapname,
    description: description
  };

  $.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) {
    var d1 = JSON.parse(data);
    if (d1.status == "success") {
      // its good reload the page
      location.href = location.href;
    }
    else {
      // its error, reset the input?
      $('#inputName').val('')
      $('#inputDescription').val('')
      $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your modal logic into the [`shown.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/) event and then search for the fields inside your modal when the ajax button is clicked.

```
$('.modal-body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { // when modal is opened

  var modal = $(this);
  var btnSubmit = modal.find('button.submitBtn');

  var ajax_url = "<?php echo APPURL;?>/ajax.php";

  btnSubmit.on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit

    var datamapname = modal.find('#inputName').val();
    var description = modal.find('#inputDescription').val();


    var data_obj = {
      call_type: 'new_row_entry_vdm',
      datamapname: datamapname,
      description: description

    };


    $.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) {
      var d1 = JSON.parse(data);
      location.href = location.href;


      if (d1.status == "error") {

        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
      } else if (d1.status == "success") {
        $('#inputName').val('')
        $('#inputDescription').val('')

        location.href = location.href;

      }

    })

  })

})
```